# How to partial match (startswith) a tuple string?

Tags: c#, string, xml-parsing, tuples

Is it possible to perform a startswith type match on a tuple string? Here is my code for an exact match:

```cs
if (responseHeaders.Contains(new Tuple<string, string>("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"))) {
    Console.WriteLine("this is a text/html document");
}
```

But I would like to match any Content Type that starts with "text/html" without having to exactly match every charset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to iterate over them and compare each item separately. Something like:

```
foreach(var header in responseHeaders)
{
    if (header.Item1 == "Content-Type" && header.Item2.StartsWith("text/html")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a text/html document");
    }
}
```

or you could maybe do it with LINQ:

```
if (responseHeaders.Any(x => x.Item1 == "Content-Type" && x.Item2.StartsWith("text/html"))
    //Write Line
```

Comment: That LINQ solution is perfect. Thank you :)